# Automate the Export from Power BI to Power Point

Tags: powerbi

I have a data set that it transformed in SQL Server and then sent to Power BI. The report is built to specs of marketing people so i cannot move to excel (needs to be pretty).

Has anyone set up a procedure to automate the export of a PBI report (filtered by a specific column) and then converted to PDF? To clearify, the data set has performance metrics of say 15 locations and i need a report for each location.

Steps:
1) data is loaded in aggregate
2) filter applied by location
3) calculated fields populated (charts etc.)
4) exported to PPTX then converted to PDF (would love to automate this step)
5) Need to remove links to PBI from PDF (no quick way found yet)
6) go to PBI and set the filter to next location and repeat

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How would you feel about just screen-shotting the PBI report and creating a PDF/PPTX file out of that?

You can also print direct to PDF:

```
Print -> Print to PDF as 'printer'
```

Comment: Is there a way to automate the screen shot? I end up creating 27 of these and that number will increase.

Comment: I guess so ( using something like https://www.seleniumhq.org/ maybe ), but at some point you should be asking if your report is well built. Perhaps you should make 27 tabs on your report so printing is easier.. Perhaps you should enable sharing so it's easily consumable.

Comment: I was hoping not to go the selenium route but i think i may. Was just wondering if anyone has attempted this at scale yet.

Comment: The report is 7 pages. I currently have 27 groups that receive reports. If i had a doc for each, each time i made a single change, i would have to change 27 pages. It is well built, the problem is with MS limiting the way we can export. We cannot add external entities to our premium server for obvious reasons. I appreciate the input though.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I don’t break any rules for saying this but our software,PBRS, is just the answer for this. Our data-driven schedules can run the Power BI reports with one or more filters applied and export it to PDF, PowerPoint, Excel etc. The filter values can be pulled from a database list as you described. 
Check it out at

https://go.christiansteven.com/power-bi-reports-scheduler-power-bi-reports-distribution-pbrs

Comment: I suggest first reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Because, in order for someone to help you, the questions need to be clear. IMHO, the code you've provided isn't enough and it's very messy. Read the article, come back and please refactor your question (code) correctly. Happy coding and welcome to SO :)